# Type error when trying to multiply two Lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a simple program where a new column is added to an existing dataframe. The new column is created by multiplying values of two existing columns.
This is the code I have written :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'Booking Code':['B001','B002','B003','B004','B005'],'Customer Name':['Veer','Umesh','Lavanya','Shobhna','Piyush'],
'No. of Tickets':[4,2,6,5,3], 'Ticket Rate':[100,200,150,250,100],'Booking Clerk':['Manish','Kishor','Manish','John','Kishor']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.to_string(index=False)
print(df)

totalamount=[int(df['No. of Tickets'])* int(df['Ticket Rate']) ]

df['Total Amounts']=totalamount
print(df)
```

Even though I've used the int() method to convert the values back to integer, it still gives the type error, the exact error being:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File Path", line 11, in <module>
    totalamount=[int(df['No. of Tickets'])* int(df['Ticket Rate']) ]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Earlier when I did not have the line `df=df.to_string(index=False)` line, and also did not use the int() function, there wasn't any error. The list was multiplied, although printed in this manner

```
[0     400
1     400
2     900
3    1250
4     300
dtype: int64]
```

But further in the code where I try to add the list to the Dataframe it gives the error `ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (5)`

I tried to look any other ways to do this, but can't seem to find any. Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this short answer:

```
df['Total Amounts'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['No. of Tickets'] * x['Ticket Rate'], axis=1)
```

output:

```
# print(df['Total Amounts'])
0     400
1     400
2     900
3    1250
4     300
Name: Total Amounts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was trying to understand the lamda function, I'm not really familiar with it. So I do have a question if you could answer it. How does ```x['No. of Tickets']``` work? Because the No. of Tickets is a part of df, but no where have we stated that x=df.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal, because we use df `lambda x : x['columnName']` iterate on values of row that you specific column name. Am i answering you comment?

Comment: Yes it does! I now get what you mean. But then I was confused as to why using ```totalamount=df['No. of Tickets']*df[Ticket Rate]``` didn't work. Because it does create a list as wanted, but when tried to add it as a separate column to the Dataframe, it shows that the number of values is not the same, i.e., ```ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (5)``` . But when we try what you've done, which I guess is somewhat similar, it works.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal, I got what you say. this happen because of this line of your code : `df=df.to_string(index=False)` if you remove this line you can write : `df['No. of Tickets'] * df['Ticket Rate']` and get what you want like this : `[400, 400, 900, 1250, 300]`

Answer (score 1):

You converted your df to a string and again reassigned it to df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'Booking Code':['B001','B002','B003','B004','B005'],'Customer Name':['Veer','Umesh','Lavanya','Shobhna','Piyush'],
'No. of Tickets':[4,2,6,5,3], 'Ticket Rate':[100,200,150,250,100],'Booking Clerk':['Manish','Kishor','Manish','John','Kishor']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
string_df = df.to_string(index=False) #Assign it to another variable!
print(string_df)

totalamount = [df['No. of Tickets'] * df['Ticket Rate'] ]

df['Total Amounts'] = totalamount
print(df)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that mistake! However, fixing this does allow the printing of the list, but another error, a type error persists when adding totalamount to the dataframe (I've mentioned in the post, for reference.) Adding it to string_df doesn't work either.